# Go back to Previous Form inside Panel (C#) winform

Tags: c#, winforms

i Have a Dashboard Panel into which i send and dispose forms.
On side Buttons they Send Form to the Dashboard Panel, After User complete their work they click on another Button which send another Form to the Dashboard. How can i go back to the Previous Form using Back Button.
Suppose **(Employee Detail)** Button send  Form to Dashboard Panel,
After Work done User Click **(All Employees)** and new Form Comes to the Panel.
Now Problem is That i have a  **"Back Button"**  So how to get previous Form (in this case "Employee Detail") into the Dashboard Panel.

I have tried having a static form in the Main Form but in this way i can only go back only one stage.
For Example:
 (Employee Detail)
 (All Employees)

But What if a have multiple forms in row

(Employee Detail Form)
(All Employees Form)
(Remove Employee Form)
(Etc)

namespace Agency.Forms
{

```
public partial class MainMenuForm : Form
{
    public static Form StaticForm;       

    private void UpdateDashBoardForm(Form myform)    //use to get form and add to panel
    {
        if (myform == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ClearDashBoard();
        myform.TopLevel = false;
        DashBaordPanel.Controls.Add(myform);
        myform.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        myform.Show();
    }

    private void ClearDashBoard()
    {

        foreach (Form item in DashBaordPanel.Controls)
        {

            if (!item.Equals(StaticForm))
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                item.Visible = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

i Expect the the Back Button should get all the forms which are previously added to the dashboard, Like Forms Should store in a Stack and After Clicking back Button should Get the Top most Form from the Stack and Pop it out from stack.[image]

Help: 
I need 2 Functions
1) will Add Form to a Static List.`void addForm(Form obj);`

2) Will Return the recent most Form from list and Remove it from the list `Form getForm();`

Comment: The ClearDashBoard() method has a bug, it does not dispose all the controls.  That happens when you modify the collection you're iterating.  In this *specific* case, you have a use-case for Controls.Remove().  Store the controls you remove in a `List<Control>`.  Now you can implement the back-button, take the last item from the list and add it back to the panel.  You do need to prevent the list from getting too large, call Dispose() on items you remove from the front of the list.  And dispose everything in the FormClosed event handler.

Comment: That's is not a bug dear! if a dispose all the Forms inside the dashboard it removes the form from the panel and i don't know but it gives an error somehow saying The Accessible form has been disposed!

Comment: It is a bug, you probably just haven't noticed it because you never add more than one form to the panel.  Just nail that down by not using foreach.

Comment: yes i did this on purpose. this will Clear all the Dashboard so The garbage collector will get the unused form there. If i can find a Better code to solve the going back to multiple form i will change this code. i know this is not going to work.

Answer (score 2):

So ar this point you are giving your next form (`myform`) to this class and then showing it and disposing of the current class which is `StaticForm`, am I right?

What you can do is add your StaticForm to a list, which keeps adding lists when you "build up" your history. Then when you want to use the back button you can just lookup the last form that is in the history and call back to that form.

Example code:

```
List<Form> FormHistory = new List<Form>( );
public static Form StaticForm;

private void UpdateDashBoardForm(Form myform)    //use to get form and add to panel
{
    FormHistory.Add( StaticForm );

    // Plus Your code.
}

private void GoBackToPreviousForm()
{
    if( FormHistory.Count > 0 )
    {
        // Plus what ever you need to do to go to the next form.
        FormHistory[ FormHistory.Count - 1 ].Show( );
        FormHistory.RemoveAt( FormHistory.Count - 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        // You are at the first loaded form.
    }
}
```

Comment: You Absolutely got me. and i think it solved my Problem too.

Comment: Great :D, Glad I could help!